# Connecting Raspberry Pi to Neurosky Mindwave

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Has anyone had any luck connecting a **Neurosky Mindwave** ([RF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency), not Bluetooth) to a **Raspberry Pi**?

I've tried both [python-mindwave](https://github.com/akloster/python-mindwave) and [mindwave-python](https://github.com/BarkleyUS/mindwave-python) without any luck. I believe it's having trouble connecting through the *pyserial* module (perhaps because of the way **Raspberry Pi** sets up the USB inputs?).

Comment: I think you are using [*Linux*](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux)?  Knowing this will help people answer your question.  You can try `lsusb` or there are `/sys/bus/usb-serial` entries too.

Comment: Can you clarify "having trouble connecting"? (What is the error) Have you gotten it to work on a Linux PC? (i.e. is the problem Pi-Specific?)